# Is there an alternate way to handle this forever running code?

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, r, i, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        while (i != 0)
        {
            r = i % 10;
            if (r == 3)
            {
                count++;
            }
            i = i / 10;
        }
    }

    printf("occurrences of 3 =%d ", count);
    return 0;
}
```

I need to find how many times the digit "3" occured between 0 to 100. But this code runs forever.

Comment: Inside your `for` loop, you do `i = i / 10;` `while (i != 0)` . Hence, the condition of `for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)` will always check with `i`: 1 (0 -> 1 due to increment at end of `for` loop). As 1 is ever `<= 100` your loop will run forever. Didn't you see this in your debugger? ;-)

Comment: You do not need nested loops to do so, numbers like 3x and x3 will count in your case that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You make `i` to `0` from inner `while` loop every time such that your `for` loop runs forever.

Use some temporary variable for inner `while` loop.

```
    int temp = i;
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        r = temp % 10;
        if (r == 3)
        {
            count++;
        }
        temp = temp / 10;
    }
```